# Why does the Moon have circular motion while a falling apple has one-dimensional motion?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

An apple and the Moon are both attracted to Earth. So why does the Moon have circular motion while an apple has one-dimensional motion?

Answer (score 2):

The moon has a large tangential velocity. If you throw the apple parallel to the ground, it also moves in a curved path.